# Type mismatch when writing my own iterator

Tags: java, generics, types, iterator

I have written my own `LinkedList` and since I don't want to iterate manually and always check for `null`. I thought I should write my own `Iterator` method to return an iterator.

My problem is, I don't really know how I can link my List and my Iterator together. I think that's the deeper reason for my `TypeMismatch` problem.

```
public class SearchList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements List<T> {

    public class Node {
        T obj;
        Node next;
        int occurences;

        public Node() {
            this.obj = null;
            this.next = null;
            this.occurences = 1;
        }
    }

    private Node head;

    //Here are my List methods
}
```

And here's the iterator method

```
@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {

    Node current = head;

    Iterator<T> iterator = new Iterator<T>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current.next != null;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            return current.next;
        }
    };
    return iterator;
}
```

Intellij complains about a type mismatch in the overridden next() method of the Iterator.

So how do I implement this the correct way?

Comment: `current.next` is a `Node`, not a `T`. It should probably be `current.next.obj`. You also need to set `current` to the next node if you want the iterator to actually iterate through the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current.next` is another `Node` instance (next node) and not the data (of type `T`)

Change it as

```
@Override
public T next() {
    T data = current.obj;
    current = current.next;
    return data;
}
```

Also, your `hasNext` condition checks `current.next != null`, and you won't be able to access the last element due to this. This might have to be changed to `current != null`

This answer assumes you want an `Iterable<T>` and not `Iterable<Node>`.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to iterate over `Node`, then you must return `Iterator<Node>`

```
@Override
public Iterator<Node> iterator() {

    Node current = head;

    Iterator<Node> iterator = new Iterator<>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current!= null;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            Node currentNode = current;
            current = current.next;
            return currentNode;
        }
    };
    return iterator;
}
```

Comment: I think `next()` should return `Node` rather than template `T`

Comment: @Michel_T. I thought the OP wanted an `Iterable<T>`

Comment: @Michel_T. I don't see `implements Iterable...` in the OP. So, what you do think the type of `Iterator` be? (and I guess we are just speculating what the OP wants). In others what do you want to iterate over? The nodes? The individual data elements (I thought the latter)

Comment: Well, why don't iterate over nodes, if you're implementing your own list? But every node must have `next()` method.

Comment: @freedeebee, shouldn't it be List not SList ?